Opening a .tex file under Emacs fails with a wrong-type-argument
I encountered a post (link follows) that led me to turn on the debugger:
What does it mean when emacs tells me "File mode specification error"?
I am attempting to open a LaTeX file called bread.tex.  Somehow this results in a reference to the PDF viewer Okular, which I do use, but which ordinarily has nothing to do with opening LaTeX files.
I haven't changed my .emacs file since yesterday, and I did not encounter this problem yesterday while opening and closing .tex files.
This morning my Windows 11 computer crashed and I had to restart it.  I did get a report of a problem in starting WSL under Windows.  (An XML transcript with my company's name redacted appears at the end of this post.)  My response was to reboot again.  I did not get the same report during this second attempt to reboot.  But when I then started Emacs under WSL and opened the file, I did encounter the problem I have outlined.  Here is what the debugger showed:
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument listp "Okular")
  #f(compiled-function (spec) #<bytecode 0x221c31f20a385d5>)("Okular")
  mapc(#f(compiled-function (spec) #<bytecode 0x221c31f20a385d5>) ("Okular" ("okular --unique %o" (mode-io-correlate "#src:%n%a")) "okular" ("dvi2tty" ("dvi2tty -q -w 132 %o")) ("xdvi" ("%(o?)xdvi" (mode-io-correlate " -sourceposition \"%n %b\" -editor \"%cS\"") ((paper-a4 paper-portrait) " -paper a4") ((paper-a4 paper-landscape) " -paper a4r") ((paper-a5 paper-portrait) " -paper a5") ((paper-a5 paper-landscape) " -paper a5r") (paper-b5 " -paper b5") (paper-letter " -paper us") (paper-legal " -paper legal") (paper-executive " -paper 7.25x10.5in") " %d") "%(o?)xdvi") ("dvips and gv" "%(o?)dvips %d -o && gv %f" ("%(o?)dvips" "gv")) ("gv" "gv %o" "gv") ("xpdf" ("xpdf -remote %s -raise %o" (mode-io-correlate " %(outpage)")) "xpdf") ("Evince" ("evince" (mode-io-correlate " -p %(outpage)") " %o") "evince") ("Atril" ("atril" (mode-io-correlate " -p %(outpage)") " %o") "atril") ("Xreader" ("reader" (mode-io-correlate " -p %(outpage)") " %o") "xreader") ("Okular" ("okular --unique %o" (mode-io-correlate "#src:%n%a")) "okular") ("xdg-open" "xdg-open %o" "xdg-open") ("PDF Tools" TeX-pdf-tools-sync-view) ("Zathura" ("zathura %o" (mode-io-correlate " --synctex-forward %n:0:\"%b\" -x \"emacsclient +%{li...")) "zathura") ("Sioyek" ("sioyek %o" (mode-io-correlate " --forward-search-file \"%b\" --forward-search-line ...")) "sioyek")))
  byte-code("\304\302\305\306\307DD\310\311\312\313\314\315\316\317\320\321\322\323\324\325\314\324\325\317\326\315\324\327\330C\331\332\333\334\335\336\6\6!\337\"\340\341%\342\10\11\"\"..." [TeX-view-predicate-list TeX-view-predicate-list-builtin TeX-view-program-list TeX-view-program-list-builtin custom-declare-variable funcall function #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x198000153e91>) "List of viewer specifications.\nThis variable can b..." :group TeX-view :type repeat list (string :tag "Name") choice (group :tag "Command" (string :tag "Command")) group :inline t :tag "Command parts" (string :tag "Command part") "Predicate and command part" nil mapc make-byte-code 257 "\300\301\2@D\211\300\242\235\203\21\0\300\242\202\25\0\211\300\242B\262\1\240\207" vconcat vector [const] 5 "\n\n(fn SPEC)" append sort #f(compiled-function (a b) #<bytecode 0x102da7a11bf6c51e>) "Predicate" "List of predicates" ((string :tag "Command part")) ((group :tag "Function" function)) ((choice :tag "Viewer executable(s)" (string :tag "One executable") (repeat :tag "List of executables" (string :tag "Name")) (const :tag "No executable" nil))) TeX-view-program-selection #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x9787fd525685820>) "Alist of predicates and viewers.\nEach entry consis..." alist :key-type [const] #f(compiled-function (a b) #<bytecode 0x102da7a11bf6c51e>) "Single predicate" ...] 35)
  require(tex)
  byte-code("\300\301!\210\300\302!\210\300\303!\210\300\304!\207" [require tex tex-style tex-ispell latex-flymake] 2)
  TeX-latex-mode()
  apply(TeX-latex-mode nil)
  latex-mode()
  set-auto-mode-0(latex-mode nil)
  set-auto-mode()
  normal-mode(t)
  after-find-file(nil t)
  find-file-noselect-1(#<buffer bread.tex> "/tmp/bread.tex" nil nil "/tmp/bread.tex" (92421 2080))
  find-file-noselect("/tmp/bread.tex" nil nil t)
  find-file("/tmp/bread.tex" t)
  funcall-interactively(find-file "/tmp/bread.tex" t)
  call-interactively(find-file nil nil)
  command-execute(find-file)

I am using GNU Emacs 29.3 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.24, cairo version 1.16.0) of 2024-06-12.  I also am using AucTeX 13.2.2.  The command LaTeX --version yields this output:
kpathsea version 6.4.0
Copyright 2024 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.43; using libpng 1.6.43
Compiled with zlib 1.3.1; using zlib 1.3.1
Compiled with xpdf version 4.04

I'm not sure it's relevant, but I'm using Version 20.12.3 of Okular.
In an attempt to circumvent this problem I removed AucTeX and installed Version 14.0.5.  This resulted in a long list of compiler errors, all of which seemed essentially the same as the one above.  Here is the complete log:
Leaving directory ‘/home/cxc_linux/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-14.0.5’

Compiling file /home/cxc_linux/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-14.0.5/auctex.el at Thu Jun 27 09:02:40 2024
Entering directory ‘/home/cxc_linux/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-14.0.5/’


<Numerous compilation for other .el files with identical errors redacted for brevity>

Compiling file /home/cxc_linux/.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-14.0.5/style/zlmtt.el at Thu Jun 27 09:02:44 2024
zlmtt.el:34:2: Error: Wrong type argument: listp, "Okular"

Even with all these errors, the package installer reported that AucTeX had been installed.  I then tried once again to open bread.tex.  The *Messages window showed this error:
File mode specification error: (wrong-type-argument listp Okular)

I'm not sure what to do to get my system working without errors now.  Any suggestions would be welcome.

XML listing of the WSL-related error I encountered while booting up the computer the first of two times this morning:
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="WSL" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="40960">0</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>3</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2024-06-27T12:29:36.2980736Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>546933</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" /> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>-----Redacted-----</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>Failed to create network endpoint with address: '172.25.34.126', assigned new address: '172.28.149.122'</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>


I don't seem to have the function TeX-latex-mode available: it's neither in the built-in TeX mode, nor in AucTeX. What does C-h f TeX-latex-mode tell you?

Now that I have AucTeX Version 14.0.5, I don't see it either.  Perhaps it's in version 13.2.2, which was installed on my machine at the time the message mentioning this mode appeared.  With the new version of AucTeX I get this message: user-error: Symbol’s function definition is void: TeX-latex-mode.

Have you restarted your emacs? It may be that the currently running session is corrupted for some reason and a restart might clear things up.

Yes, I've done that several times, and I've also rebooted the computer and then restarted Emacs.  I continue to get the error.  Furthermore, key bindings that are ordinarily established when I enter latex files no longer are put into effect.  Here is one line of key-definition that no longer takes place:
(eval-after-load "latex"
'(progn
(define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "C-c u") #'cbc-insert-unit)))

There seems to be a more fundamental problem.  Just executing (require 'tex) gives these errors:
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument listp "Okular")
#f(compiled-function (spec) #<bytecode 0x220cce6de9985d5>)("Okular")
mapc(#f(compiled-function (spec) #<bytecode 0x220cce6de9985d5>) ("Okular" ("okular --unique
byte-code("\304\302\305\306\307DD\310\311\312\313\314\315\316\317\320\321\322\323\324\325
require(tex)
(progn (require 'tex))
eval((progn (require 'tex)) t)
...

Try M-x locate-library RET tex RET and make sure you are loading the one from AucTeX, not the built-in one.

I got to the bottom of the problem by commenting out nearly my entire .emacs file and reintroducing pieces of it bit by bit, the time-honored but painful method.  I uncovered several problems, but the chief one was this:
'(TeX-view-program-list
  '("Okular"
    ("okular --unique %o"
     (mode-io-correlate "#src:%n%a"))
    "okular"))

I will pursue how to once again specify Okular as my pdf viewer, but the LaTeX formatting and modes all work once again as they did before, although now with a new version of AucTeX.

If you comment out 1/2, then 3/4, 7/8, 15/16, etc. then it's a binary search, which is quick. Still a bit tedious, but much better than just commenting arbitrary or sequential bits.

Good suggestion!
